# Best strategy for the secretary problem with known distribution

Tags: optimization, stochastic-programming, dynamic-programming

The optimal strategy for the well known [secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) with $n$ candidates is to reject the first $\lceil \frac{n}{e} \rceil-1$ candidates, and then select the first subsequent applicant that is better than all previous ones.

If $n=3$, this optimal "threshold based" strategy selects the best applicant $50\%$ of the time.

However, in [this document](https://studentnet.cs.manchester.ac.uk/pgt/2014/COMP60342/COMP60342-2013-DynamProg2-Secretary.pdf) from Manchester University (pages 5-10), another strategy based on dynamic programming is described, which yields an optimal choice approximately $70\%$ of the time (based on my simulations which match the paper's results). Note that in this version of the problem, the distribution of the "value" of the candidates is known, and used in the strategy.

**My question**: is the strategy based on the threshold optimal only when the distribution is not known? Or is there a contradiction somewhere?

---

*Note*: A relevant tag for this question would be "online optimization," but it does not exist.